# retrieve selected value from a binded combobox in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox

I am trying to retrieve the selected value from a binded combobox.

In the below code, I have binded the combobox named “LSF_Combo” to another combobox  “Queue _Combo” . I am trying to retrieve the selected value from the “Queue_Combo”, using `Queue_Combo.get()` method, but I am not able to do so, since its scope is limited within `LSF_fields_Enable(event)` inner function. I am able to retrieve the selected value of LSF_Combo using `LSF_Combo.get()` method.

Please let me know if anyone has suggestions for retrieving the selected value from the “Queue_Combo” combobox and furhter nested comboboxes "MT_Combo: and "Merge_Combo", so that I should be able to access and assign these to a variable outside the "LSF_Fields_Enable" function scope.

For example, If i had selected 'priority' from "Queue_Combo" and had selected "MT" from "MT_Combo", i should be able to assign these strings to  variables outisde LSF_Fields_Enable(event) function.  From the 'def run_program()' variable 'b' should have sting equals to 'priority' (since i have selected this) and variable 'c' should have string equals to 'MT'.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
root.geometry("800x450")

def Gui_main():
    Queue_Combo_list = ['normal', 'priority', 'devices', 'grid']
    Queue_Combo = ttk.Combobox(root, values=Queue_Combo_list, width=10, state="readonly")
    Merge_Combo_list = ['LST_SET_ML', 'LST_SET_EQU']
    Merge_Combo = ttk.Combobox(root, values=Merge_Combo_list, width=12)
    MT_Combo_list = ['MT', 'MTFLEX']
    MT_Combo = ttk.Combobox(root, values=MT_Combo_list, width=10)

    def LSF_Fields_Enable(event):
        # global Queue_Combo, VCO_Combo, OS_Combo
        VCO_1 = None
        if LSF_Combo.get() == 'LSF':
            # # section for Queue Type
            Queue_Combo_label = tk.Label(root, text="Queue: ").grid(row=2, column=1, padx=5,sticky=W)
            Queue_Combo.set("normal")
            Queue_Combo.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=55, pady=5, sticky=W)

            def MT_MT_flex(choice):

                    def Manage_run_mode(choice):
                        # if Merge_Combo.get() == 'LSF_SET_EQU' or 'LSF_SET_MAN':
                        if Merge_Combo.get() != 'LSF_SET_ML':
                            label = tk.Label(root, text="CPU No:").grid(row=4, column=3, padx=10,sticky=tk.W)
                            CPU_radio_button = tk.IntVar()
                            R1 = Radiobutton(root, text="2", variable=CPU_radio_button, value=1).place(x=50, y=520)

                    if MT_Combo.get() == 'MT':
                        # # section for choosing a file version
                        Merge_Combo_label = tk.Label(root, text="Merge: ").grid(row=6, column=2, padx=10,sticky=W)
                        Merge_Combo.set("LST_SET_ML")
                        Merge_Combo.grid(row=6, column=2, padx=65, pady=15, sticky=tk.E)
                        Merge_Combo.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>',Manage_run_mode)

            MT_Combo_label = tk.Label(root, text="MT/MTflex: ").grid(row=2, column=3, padx=10,sticky=W)
            MT_Combo.set("MT")
            MT_Combo.grid(row=2, column=4, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=tk.E)
            MT_Combo.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>',MT_MT_flex)

    # LSF_Fields_Enable()

    LSF_Combo_label = tk.Label(root, text="Fill: ").grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)
    LSF_Combo_list = ['LSF', 'LOCAL']
    LSF_Combo = ttk.Combobox(root, values=LSF_Combo_list, width=10, state="readonly", background='white')
    LSF_Combo.set('LSF')
    LSF_Combo.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=25, pady=5, sticky=W)
    LSF_Combo.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>',  LSF_Fields_Enable)
    Queue_Combo.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', lambda _: print(Queue_Combo.get()))
    MT_Combo.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', lambda _: print(MT_Combo.get()))
    Merge_Combo.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', lambda _: print(Merge_Combo.get()))

    # a = LSF_Combo.bind("<Return", LSF_Fields_Enable)

    def run_program():
        a = LSF_Combo.get()
        print(a)
        b = Queue_Combo.get()
        print(b)
        c = MT_Combo.get()
        d = Merge_Combo.get()


    close = Button(root, text ='close', command= root.destroy).grid(row=10, column=2, pady=60, sticky=E)
    check_combo_get =Button (root, text ='check_combo_get', command = run_program).grid(row=10, column=1, padx=15,pady=60, sticky=E)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Gui_main()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not an easy way to fix this problem in your setup.
But the solution is easy, if you just go ahead and restructure your code a little:

1. Define the combobox outside the **LSF_Fields_Enable** function and also asign its values at startup.
   `Queue_Combo_list = ['normal', 'priority', 'devices', 'grid']`
   `Queue_Combo = ttk.Combobox(root, values=Queue_Combo_list, width=10, state="readonly")`
2. Now bind the **ComboboxSelected** Event to whatever function you want to have (in this example a simple print).
   `Queue_Combo.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', lambda _: print(Queue_Combo.get()))`

And there you go!
Now the print function is executed every time the selection changes for the queue-combobox.

Hope this helps :)

EDIT:
In the updated Code below I reformated your code to make it more readable and to achieve what you wanted to have.
The Value of the ComboBoxes are now assigned to variables ("Queue_Combo_variable", "LSF_Combo_variable").
You can access their values using:

```
Queue_Combo_variable.get()
```

I tried my best to comment the entire to be as understandable as possible. Let me now if this is how you imagined it to be!

NEW CODE:

```
from tkinter import ttk, Tk, Label, Button, StringVar
from tkinter.constants import W, E


def Gui_main():
  # Create tkinter (window) instance
  root = Tk()
  root.geometry("300x250")
  # Define LSF_Combox (Combobox)
  LSF_Combo_variable = StringVar()
  LSF_Combo_label = Label(root, text="Fill: ")    # Label
  LSF_Combo_label.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)
  LSF_Combo_list = ['LSF', 'LOCAL']
  LSF_Combo = ttk.Combobox(root, values=LSF_Combo_list, textvariable=LSF_Combo_variable, width=10, state="readonly", background='white')
  LSF_Combo.set('LSF')
  LSF_Combo.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=25, pady=5, sticky=W)  # and place it on the screen





  # Define Queue_Combo (Combobox)
  Queue_Combo_variable = StringVar()  
  Queue_Combo_label = Label(root, text="Queue: ")   # Label
  Queue_Combo_list = ['normal', 'priority', 'devices', 'grid']
  Queue_Combo = ttk.Combobox(root, values=Queue_Combo_list, textvariable=Queue_Combo_variable, width=10, state="readonly")                                                     
  # ==> The Queue_Combo_variable now always stores the value which is currently selected in the queue_combo (box)




  #################################################################################################################################
  #### ==> Through the following code the specfied function (LSF_Combo_changed) is always called, once the variable value changes #
  #################################################################################################################################
  LSF_Combo_variable.trace_add("write", lambda _0, _1, _2: LSF_Combo_changed())
  Queue_Combo_variable.trace_add("write", lambda _0, _1, _2: print(Queue_Combo_variable.get()))
  # If you don't understand, what all of this does, it doesn't matter just now, that you can change the print function to be the function you want to call instead!




  # This function is now executed every time when the LSF_Combo (box) is changed (=> "Something has been selected in the left combobox")
  def LSF_Combo_changed():
    # If "LSF" has been selected, show the Queue_Combo Box
    if LSF_Combo.get() == 'LSF':
      Queue_Combo.set("normal")
      Queue_Combo.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=55, pady=5, sticky=W)
      Queue_Combo_label.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=10,sticky=W)
      return Queue_Combo.get()
    else:   # If that hasn't been selected, "forget" the position of the Queue_Combo Box & Label ("Hide them")
      Queue_Combo.grid_forget()
      Queue_Combo_label.grid_forget()
      return None
  


  
  # Close Button
  close_button = Button(root, text ='close', command= root.destroy)
  close_button.grid(row=10, pady=60, sticky=E)
  # Show window (tkinter instance)
  root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  Gui_main()
```

Comment: I want to have access to Queue_Combo.get() anywhere inside the Gui_main() function. Is it possible to assign selected value from Queue_combo to a variable?                                             
Further I have a need for implementing many other combobox based on selected value from Queue_Combo combobox (here nesting comboboxes), so i need access to all the selected values of to be implemented comboboxes inside the Gui_main()

Comment: In my code snippet above the Queue_Combo is available throughout the entire gui_main method.
Just refrence it using it's variable name "Queue_Combo" and add the method you want to perform (e.g. .set => Queue_Combox.set("example_value"))

If you want the value of the combobox in a variable you can specifiy "textvariable=your_string_var". You have to specifiy a variable of type IntVar, StringVar or similar. Take a look at this for more information: [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#coupling-widget-variables).

For the additional methods just repeat what I described above

Comment: I want to retrieve the selected value from combobox and assign it to a variable outside the LSF_Fields _Enable() function.  Sorry, I just might be missing your explanation, could you please edit your answer. I have updated original code post as well.

Comment: Is there a way  to get selected value from below line? instead of print. Say if i assign it to a variable?

Queue_Combo.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', lambda _: print(Queue_Combo.get())) 

to 
a = Queue_Combo.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', lambda _: Queue_Combo.get()) . 
please correct me on the syntax.

Comment: Ok, I updated my code (and explanation). Let me know if this is fine now